# Is there a way to force JMX jmeter plugin to generate a graph when running through commandline?

Tags: csv, jmeter, jmx

I am trying to run jmeter tests through the gradle plugin and through GUI.

However, when I use the JMeter JMX monitoring plugin, I am able to generate a csv file of results, but cannot generate graphs out of that csv file in jmeter.

Is there a wat I can force the JMX plugin to output the graph at the end of execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the JMX monitoring plugin is useless.  I would highly recommend enabling the "Mission control" options on the JVM (versions 1.7.0_40+) and then use jmc.exe (Mission control) or VisualVM.exe (with jstatd.exe running and VisualGC plugins installed) instead.   With mission control you can make a "flight recorder" recording of the entire jvm activity.  Way better than graphing from Jmeter I think.   I wouldn't waste my time on JMX recording from jmeter.

```
$java -jar MyApp.jar
$jcmd 40019 VM.command_line
$jcmd 40019 VM.check_commercial_features
$jcmd 40019 JFR.check
$jcmd 40019 VM.unlock_commercial_features
$jcmd 40019 VM.check_commercial_features
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to measure the JVM metrics while the jmeter tests are running to see if my application goes beyond a certain limit on heap usage while load testing. Can Mission Control help me do this in a batch mode?

Comment: Just put these args on the JVM that you want to trace: `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder` .  Then, run a separate command line script to do a flight recorder session on it.